# How to format datetime to "yyyy-MM-dd"

Tags: c#, datetime

I want to convert date format to this `yyyy-MM-dd`.

Below is my code:

```
var TimeOfOffer = priceCost.TimeOfOfferChange;
DateTime ChangesOnTimeOfOfferChange = DateTime.ParseExact(TimeOfOffer, "dd-MM-yyyy HH:mm:ss", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
priceCostViewmodel.TimeOfOfferChange = priceCost.TimeOfOfferChange;
```

But I am getting exception

> String was not recognized as a valid DateTime.

`priceCost.TimeOfOfferChange` is in string format i.e. "9/26/2016 4:38:58 PM"
and wants to pass in string as well i.e. `priceCostViewmodel.TimeOfOfferChange`

Comment: It's really not clear what your problem with formatting is - your error is related to *parsing* a string to `DateTime`.

Comment: try DateTime.ParseExact(TimeOfOffer, "dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm:ss", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture); instead

Comment: Looks like "someone" downvotes answers instead of asking for clarifications, or adding informations. That's not how StackOverflow works.

Comment: @Kilazur Perhaps your answer did not actually answer the question correctly?

Comment: @Kilazur Your answer was just wrong. It is deleted now, but if it wasn't I would have downvoted it.

Answer (score 4):

Your string format and your date format do not actually match.

The date string:

> ```
> 9/26/2016 4:38:58 PM
> ```

Is in the format:

```
M/dd/yyyy h:mm:ss tt
```

Therefore, you need:

```
DateTime.ParseExact(TimeOfOffer, "M/dd/yyyy h:mm:ss tt", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture)
```

At this point, if you want the resultant in `yyyy-MM-dd` format, it's as simple as:

```
var dt = DateTime.ParseExact(TimeOfOffer, "M/dd/yyyy h:mm:ss tt", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
var formatted = dt.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd");
```

But, I suggest that you don't actually *need* the result as a string, since you're comparing them instead.

Answer (score 1):

This seems to work. You need to parse the string in the exact format it was supplied. Once you have a correctly parsed `DateTime` object, you can output it in any format.

```
string inputFormat = "M/d/yyyy h:m:s tt"; //Use this format for parsing
string outputFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd"; //Use this format for outputting

var TimeOfOffer = "9/26/2016 4:38:58 PM";
DateTime ChangesOnTimeOfOfferChange = DateTime.ParseExact(TimeOfOffer, inputFormat, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
string output = ChangesOnTimeOfOfferChange.ToString(outputFormat);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use

> "dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm:ss aa"

instead of

> "dd-MM-yyyy HH:mm:ss"